# Perspective projection of a circle: what is the size of the semi-major axis?

Tags: geometry, circles, projective-geometry

It can be proven that the perspective projection (or camera projection) of a circle is an ellipse. But I also need to prove that the semi-major axis has the same size as the radius of the original circle.
Any idea on how to prove it?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I take a photo of the circular cross section of the moon using my 35mm camera, then the resulting image on my 35mm film is certainly smaller than the moon itself, along any axis. Nevertheless, this transformation from plane in the world world to plane of the film would usually be considered a perspective transformation. So unless you have a more restricted definition of a projective transformation than what is usually used, your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: I am sorry, I have expressed myself unclearly. What I meant is that that the semi-major axis is proportional to the radius. I think it should be true if the plane of the circle is not too far from being orthogonal, depending also on the radius size vs the distance from the circle to the camera. I don't know what the maximum possible angle is either.

Comment: @CarSim: This doesn't make things much clearer: in the preimage you have a circle and therefore don't have a semi-major axis, while in the image you don't have a radius since you no longer have a circle. Therefore you can't speak about proportionality the way you do.

Comment: What I mean is that the semi-major axis of the projected circle is proportional to the radius of the original circle and depends on the distance between the camera and the circle.